# Firebase: Issue in Tracking Installs/Events from Google Ads Campaign in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase to track the installs from google ads campaign. I have tried all the solutions available on Stack overflow and Github as well but it did't work for me. Let me explain each step I am doing:

1. Register application on Firebase and add these install pods
   **'Firebase/Analytics'** and **'FirebaseCore'**
2. Add **SKAdNetworkItems**
   in info.plist as well.
3. Added the required frameworks and libraries i.e. **AdSupportFramework**, **iAd framework**, **libAdidAccess**, **libGoogleAnalyticsServices**.
4. Add the **Appstore ID** in firebase project as well.
5. Added the **IDFA** permission i.e. **ATTrackingManager** as well.
6. Configuring the Firebase in **Appdelegate** as well. These are all steps I am doing to track custom campaign.

Now I am getting all the events like first_open and other screen events on firebase console but it didn't show me the events related to my **custom google ad campaign**.

Is there any solution or am I missing something? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ? I am also facing this. Tried everything but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Google Ads related events you're referring to.

If you wanted to track the number of installs coming from your Google Ad Campaign, you could check the first_open conversions report.

Go to Analytics>Conversions>first_open. From there, you could filter the data using the [Comparisons](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9271392?hl=en#:%7E:text=site%20or%20app-,Comparisons,-Apply%20comparisons%20to) feature with "Traffic source" and select the campaign you want.

[image]